# Sizeof and Strlen

Tags: c++, sizeof, strlen

I am trying to implement an encryption using a Salt and a Password. And since the recommended size for a Salt is 64 bits, I declared.

```
char Salt[8];
```

I used RAND_pseudo_bytes to get a random Salt this way:

```
RAND_pseudo_bytes((unsigned char*)Salt, sizeof Salt);
```

And because the hexdump output was different in length(sometimes 5, mostly 24 bytes) each time I compiled because I wrongly used strlen instread of sizeof:

`RAND_pseudo_bytes((unsigned char*)Salt, strlen(Salt));`

I tried the following line to figure out what's happening:

```
printf("\n%d\n",strlen(Salt));
```

which outputs 24 each time.

So, my question is: Why is the strlen(Salt)=24 when I declared Salt's length 8(sizeof(Salt)=8)? I would understand a 9(with the '\0', although not entirely sure how exactly would that happen), but 24 strikes me as odd. Thank you.

Comment: Presumably because you don't have a null-terminated string, so you're invoking *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strlen` is going to walk down the pointer you gave it and count the number of bytes until it reaches a null byte.  In this case, your char array of 8 bytes has no null bytes, so `strlen` happily continues past the boundary into a region of memory beyond the defined char array on the stack, and whatever happens to be there will determine the behaviour of `strlen`.  In this case, 24 bytes past the beginning of the array, there was a null byte.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `char` to represent bytes.
2. Over half of the values of a byte are not printable, i.e. they don't have corresponding printable values.
3. I suggest you iterate over the array of `uint8_t` using `printf("0x%02X\n", array[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

[`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen)searches for the first null character and counts all bytes excluding that null byte.
A salt is 8 non-zero bytes - and there's no guarantee that the next character is a null byte.

That's why sizeof and strlen differ.

Comment: I'm even wrong: a salt can contain bytes with value zero as well, so a zero in the middle will result in strlen() returning too little...

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is an operator that returns the number of bytes needed to store a specific data structure. When applied to an an array of characters, it represents of the three cases where the name of the array does not decay to the pointer to its first element (the other two are the usage of & and the initialization via a string literal).

`strlen` is instead a function, assuming that its input is a null-terminated sequence of characters. Because when you pass the name of the array of characters to a function, it does decay to the pointer of its first element, `strlen` has no way to know the size of the original data structure (like sizeof does). All it gets is a pointer to char. The only way it can determine the end of the string is by running through the sequence of characters, looking for a '\0'. In your case, it cannot find one before the 24th byte in memory. That happens by pure chance.

Try initializing your array with:

```
char Salt[8] = {0};
```

And make sure that your `RAND_pseudo_bytes` function preserves the sentinel '\0' in the treated string.

Answer (score 0):

**Addressing Your Question about `strlen()`**

What `strlen()` is counting is the number of bytes until the first `'\0'` in memory.

```
char Salt[9] = { '\0' };
```

Will initialize `Salt` with all `'\0'`s.

---

NOTE: As @OliCharlesworth pointed out, Salt can have embedded NULLs. Don't use any `str*()` methods. You need to use `mem*()` methods only and keep track of the length yourself. Don't rely on `sizeof` because arrays are turned into pointers when passed to functions.

Comment: Even that won't necessarily work; a random set of bytes isn't a string; it could contain 0-valued bytes itself.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the null termination of `salt`, as others pointed out, you need to change the format specifier in `printf` to `%zu` because `strlen` return type is `size_t`.  Using wrong specifier invokes *undefined behavior*.